# Creality CR 6 SE firmware

Tags: firmware, creality, creality-cr-6

I recently bought Creality CR 6 SE, I learned there are third party firmware available, I want to know which one is best known for CR-6

Comment: Welcome to 3D SE! What research have you already done? What kind of features are you looking for? Do you have any mods on the printer already that the firmware would need to have? Please [edit] with more information.

Comment: I'm quite new to 3D printing world i do not have that much experience, while just learning about my printer i watched some videos where people were up grading their 3d printer firmware released by some 3rd party, as i came to know that more efficient firmware are available just wanted to know better one, based on experienced user's opinion.

Comment: The recommendation that has been given to others, and I as well, is to get to know your printer, what it does, how it does it, then look into doing the upgrades.